Как сделать все превью картинки на одинаковый уровень?
Всем привет!
Надо сделать, чтобы у коротких заголовках в новостях был отступ равносильно длинному заголовку
А у самого длинного заголовка не было отступа
Соответственно картинки должны идти ровно с другими
Как такое можно реализовать через css?
Сайт: https://nppesto.ru/news/


Либо JS, либо subgrid.

@OliverPatterson, table подходит

Добавь пример своей разметки прямо в вопрос

@Grundy не видел такой реализации еще)

@OliverPatterson, grid - это те же таблицы только в css - а тут явно в разметке указываются

@OliverPatterson, вместо subgrid можно contents.

Всем спасибо за ответы
Решил следующим образом
.landing-block-node-title-container > h5.landing-block-node-title {

min-height: 75px;
}

